# How to select the li element when clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following code. As soon as I move away the cursor the background color back to white right now. How can I select the `li` element when the user clicks?

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/2.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2" id="sidebar-wrapper">
  <div id="sidebar">
    <ul class="nav list-group" style="cursor:pointer;">
      <li class="active">
        <a class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-home icon-1x"></i>Work Order</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-home icon-1x"></i>Work Order Jobs</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Clicks are the province of javascript.

Answer (score 5):

Since you already use jQuery, why not just using the click function.

For selecting only **one** item:

```
$('.nav li').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f9hr5Lgf/)**

For selecting **multiple** items:

```
$('.nav li').click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('active');
  }
});
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kf60pv0k/)**

In your CSS, override the `background-color` as follows. It's actually set on the `<a>` tag, not the `<li>` in Bootstrap.

```
.nav>li.active>a {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: @Pangloss the second jsfiddle is close but why is not holding the background color? i have remove the red and tried with this `background-color: #eee` but does not seems to work

Comment: @AbuHamzah Updated the answer again with two options.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an active class to your links.

HTML

```
<a class="list-group-item active>Work Order</a>
```

CSS

```
.list-group-item.active {
    background-color: gray
}
```

To change background-color on click, you have to use jQuery.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(".nav li a").click(function(){
     $('li a.active').removeClass('active');
     $(this).addClass('active') ;
  });
});
```

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8q93146k/1/)

Comment: I don't think you understand the question, i don't want to select background-color by default, only if/when the user clicks on the `li` element

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8q93146k/1/), is this what you are looking for then?

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this, where you add a `label` and an `input` to your `li`, and no script is needed.

[Update fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/4w70knfy/6/)

HTML

```
<label><input type="radio" class="hideme" name="li">
  <a class="list-group-item">
    <i class="icon-home icon-1x"></i>Work Order Jobs
  </a>
</label>
```

CSS

```
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
.hideme {
  display: none;
}
.hideme:checked + .list-group-item{
    background-color: gray
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use it like this:

```
       <style type="text/css">
            .nav li.active {
             background-color:grey;
            }
        </style>
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2" id="sidebar-wrapper">
          <div id="sidebar">
            <ul class="nav list-group" style="cursor:pointer;">
              <li class="active">
                <a class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-home icon-1x"></i>Work Order</a>
              </li>
              <li>
              <a class="list-group-item"><i class="icon-home icon-1x"></i>Work Order Jobs</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
```

and jQuery like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#sidebar li").click(function(){
         $("#sidebar li").removeClass('active');
         $(this).addClass('active') ;
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

put your li tag in another a tag then use any of these pseudo-classes
[w3schools pseudo classes](http://http:/http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp)

```
/* unvisited link */
    a:link {
        color: #FF0000;
    }

/* visited link */
a:visited {
    color: #00FF00;
}

/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
    color: #FF00FF;
}

/* selected link */
a:active {
    color: #0000FF;
```

Comment: not sure i understand, i have jsfiddle in my question modify it and let me know.

Comment: I see your line of thought, however this is not what the OP is looking for based on his image.